# how to fix mobile device web page height issue while orientation event triggers

Tags: jquery-mobile, iframe, html, mobile-website

I am new to it and trying to create a simple mobile phone web page which calls external web pages. I have a button at bottom of page it is fixed. what i does, i call another page from same folder which has external links, i call the page through Object element. I am facing height problem when device in landscape view, only half of the page is display and the scroll bar also not moving further down. same when i click on external link of the called page.

need suggestion and help.........

```
 <content style="width:95%;">   
    <!--<iframe src="h2.htm" id="iframe_a"></iframe>-->
    <object id="vp" type="text/html" data="h2.htm" style="width:100%; overflow:scroll;"></object>
    </content>
    <!--<div id="siteloader"></div>
    <script>
     $("#siteloader")
        .html('<object data="h2.htm">');
    </script>-->
    <div id="downloadButton" style="position:fixed; bottom:0; z-index:2; background:#fff; width:100%;"><input TYPE=SUBMIT Value="DOWNLOAD AT&T REMOTE SUPPORT" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Your page markup pls.

Comment: here i posted my markup, I tired with alternate way to bring it